# iPhone Bluetooth application to connect to a Bluetooth printer

Tags: iphone, bluetooth, printing

Has anybody succeeded in developing a bluetooth application on the iPhone that prints to a Bluetooth printer?

I have been investigating the feasibility of developing an iPhone application that could print to a Bluetooth-enabled printer.  I've gone through the most of the postings in this thread and was confused by the mail exchanges.

As per my analysis:

[Gamekit](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html) - can be used for bluetooth connectivity between iPhones and IPods **ONLY**

[Bonjour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonjour_(software)) - can be used for wi-fi connectivity between iPhones/IPods and bonjour-enabled printer

We can use an external accessory to connect to a third party Bluetooth-enabled printer provided the 3rd-party printer complies with the necessary regulations from Apple (registering  for either  “Made for iPod”/ “Works with iPhone”, and also customizing their printer with specific hardware/software, etc.)

Could someone please share their experiences?

Answer (score 6):

You want their [external accessory framework](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/ExternalAccessory/Reference/ExternalAccessoryFrameworkReference/index.html). Not GameKit. Happy coding!

> The External Accessory framework provides support for communicating with external hardware connected to an iPhone OS–based device through the 30-pin dock connector or **wirelessly using Bluetooth.**

(This is exactly what you were looking for)

Comment: could you reference to a sample code.I used sample codes provided by apple doc but this is not working

Comment: I have the same question to print via bluetooth

Answer (score 1):

To detect and connect to external devices `ExternalAccessoryFramework` should be used.Me too developing an application for connecting `iphone` to other hardware devices via `bluetooth` .A'm facing the problem with the `protocol`.The `protocol` should be the hardware supported ones and the protocol should be given in the `info plist file`..
Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

You can want to try this Bluetooth printer, which is Apple MFI approved

http://www.bluebamboo.com/other_file/P25i%20Datasheet%20%28EN%29%20v1.0%2009-Oct-2011.pdf

Comment: wang can i prit document from iphone to printer using bluetooth ?

Answer (score -1):

I would bet that you would need to use Bonjour and Wi-Fi for this application.  The bluetooth hardware is restricted to gameplay from what I've seen.

Comment: It's restricted to `GameKit`, only for transferring data between iDevices, but can be for non-GamePlay use.

Comment: But the printer is only Bluetooth enabled. The printer is neither Wi-Fi nor Bonjour enabled - Please comment

Comment: `The External Accessory framework provides support for communicating with external hardware connected to an iPhone OS–based device through the 30-pin dock connector or wirelessly using Bluetooth.`

Answer (score -3):

well i have sucsessfully accomplished bt printing on a customers I-phone both devices have to be in discovery mode to do so and then the combination wireless and bt will allow only photo printing though otherwise you will need an app